# lumen.ERROR: ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, joomla, lumen, lumen-5.3

I Create Restapi for my Joomla Site using lumen. I got Following Error in Lumen Route File.

```
lumen.ERROR: ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\CategoriesController does not exist in /var/www/j2mobapp/plugins/system/j2mobrest/api/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:749
```

My Route File Code :

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'api/v2','namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function($app)
{

$app->get('appbanners/{id}', 'CategoriesController@getBannerImag'); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

What about deleting this from the group:

```
'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'
```

As it is a default. That's why you see it doubled.

So unless you put them in a custom folder in your `Controller` folder, for example `Admin` then you will need to add `'namespace' => 'Admin'` so each controller in the group will be prefixed as `App\Http\Controllers\Admin`

Also make sure that in your `CategoriesController` you have the namespace correct at the top of the class which is:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Comment: after Delete "'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'" i got Not NotFoundHttpException in RoutesRequests.php line 679

Comment: Then check the namespace in your controller class is it correct as I mentioned above.

Comment: Also make sure you have the {id} in your database if you bound the model in controller.